# how to set package.json for first build electron

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

```
"devDependencies": {
"asar": "^0.14.6",
"electron": "^4.0.5",
"electron-packager": "^13.0.1"
}
```

I want to build electron app.
So I'd like to know if the package should be included in the DepDefendencies section as above.
What did I miss?

Comment: It should go in the `dependencies` not devDependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to let [npm do this for you](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init).

create a folder for your project then go into that folder and run, follow the prompts:

```
npm init
```

Npm will create a package.json for you. Then to set up electron run follow their [website](https://electronjs.org/):

```
npm i -D electron@latest
```

Which produces something like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Then you can add other tools like the [electon-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager):

```
npm install electron-packager --save-dev
```

The --save-dev are tools used for your development, and will be stored in the devDependencies, any libraries that you need to run your application are saved in dependencies and use the --save switch.